# Cómo conseguir que esta función sirva en el index

Tags: php, mysqli

Tengo un *index.php* que es este:

```
<?php

 session_start();
 require_once("funciones.php");

 if(!$_REQUEST){ 
    require_once("links.html");

 }elseif (isset($_REQUEST["enlace"])) { 
     if($_REQUEST["enlace"]=="altas"){ 
         require_once("formInsertar.html"); 
     }elseif($_REQUEST["enlace"] == "buscar"){
         require_once("formBuscar.html");
     }
}elseif(isset($_REQUEST["insertar"])){
    $con=conexion("localhost", "root", "", "articulos");
    insertar($con, "INSERT INTO articulos (codarticulo, nombre, pc, pv, cantidad, tipo) 
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    cerrar($con);
}elseif(isset($_REQUEST["buscar"])){
    $busqueda=$_REQUEST["busqueda"];
    $con=conexion("localhost", "root", "", "articulos");
    buscar($con, "SELECT * FROM articulos WHERE nombre LIKE '%$busqueda%'");
    cerrar($con);
}

?>
```

Y en el archivo *funciones.php* tengo la función siguiente para que una persona busque en un input el tipo de producto (pantalones, zapatos...) que quiera visualizar. La cosa es que estoy empezando con PHP y MySQL y del procedimental a POO, pues necesito ayuda. (La función para insertar funciona perfectamente).

La función para buscar es la siguiente:

```
function buscar($con, $sql){

    $resultado=mysqli_query($con, $sql);

while($fila=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    echo "Código de producto: " . $fila['codarticulo'] . "<br> ";
    echo "Nombre del producto: " . $fila['nombre'] . "<br> ";
    echo "Precio de compra: " . $fila['pc'] . "<br> ";
    echo "Precio de venta: " . $fila['pv'] . "<br> ";
    echo "Cantidad de stock: " . $fila['cantidad'] . "<br> ";
    echo "Tipo de procucto: " . $fila['tipo'] . "<br> ";
    echo "<hr>";
}

}
```

He hecho un edit por la respuesta de A. Cedano., que me ayudó a que ya por lo menos no me salga ningún error.

Sale toda la página en blanco, como si no entrara al while ni nada.

Sé que no debería usar mysqli_query() para esto y que falla la seguridad.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que en la función buscar no necesitas recuperar el criterio de búsqueda, ni tampoco re-escribir la instrucción SQL. Si observas bien, la instrucción de construye en `index.php`, sólo que allí falta recuperar el criterio de búsqueda desde el `_$REQUEST`

O sea, sería hacer esto en `index.php` :

```
}elseif(isset($_REQUEST["buscar"])){
    $busqueda=$_REQUEST['busqueda'];
    $con=conexion("localhost", "root", "", "articulos");
    buscar($con, "SELECT * FROM articulos WHERE nombre LIKE '%$busqueda%'");
    cerrar($con);
}
```

Y en  `funciones.php`, modificar el método así:

```
function buscar($con, $sql){
    $resultado=mysqli_query($con, $sql);

    while($fila=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        echo "Código de producto: " . $fila['codarticulo'] . "<br> ";
        echo "Nombre del producto: " . $fila['nombre'] . "<br> ";
        echo "Precio de compra: " . $fila['pc'] . "<br> ";
        echo "Precio de venta: " . $fila['pv'] . "<br> ";
        echo "Cantidad de stock: " . $fila['cantidad'] . "<br> ";
        echo "Tipo de procucto: " . $fila['tipo'] . "<br> ";
        echo "<hr>";
    }
}
```

> **NÓTESE** que he cambiado el parámetro `MYSQLI_BOTH` a `MYSQLI_ASSOC`. Porque el primero te trae los datos dos veces, como
>   array asociativo y numérico, lo cual recarga la memoria, trayendo
>   datos que no vas a usar.

## Sobre el ámbito de las variables

En tu error inicial parece que pensabas que por el simple hecho de incluir `fuciones.php` ya  `$busqueda` sería visible en `index.php`. En PHP las variables son de ámbito local, o sea, existen solamente dentro de las funciones donde son declaradas. Si en cualquier archivo declaras una variable dentro de una función, si intentas usarla fuera de ella te dirá que la variable no existe, aunque estés en el mismo archivo.

> ## Sobre la seguridad
>
> Tu código es vulnerable a ataques de *Inyección SQL*. Un usuario mal
>   intencionado podría tomar el control de tu sistema manipulando
>   maliciosamente variables como `$busqueda` que pasas a ejecución
>   directa. Considera usar consultas preparadas para prevenir este
>   riesgo.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por tu respuesta. También intenté hacer lo que dices, pero no me sale nada. Se queda la página en blanco, como si no entrara al while. Y sí, sé que la seguridad del código es inexistente, pero estoy estudiando y en clase nos mandan hacer esto primero para después usar PDO y todas las sentencias preparadas para evitar la inyección. Poco a poco :) Gracias de nuevo.

Comment: Entiendo @triplespicy. Al código le faltan controles. Debes verificar si el dato está en `$_REQUEST` o no. Y antes del `while` debes verificar si hay filas o no. Dado que es una práctica, dime qué cosas te permiten usar y podría modificar la respuesta para establecer esos controles en el código.